# How to constraint movement on xcode iphone?

Tags: ios, swift

I have got an object and I only want to move it in the second half of the screen.

I tried the code below but it only works for top half

```
let halfx = self.bounds.midX
self.center.x = max(halfx, self.center.x)
self.center.x = min(self.superview!.bounds.size.width-halfx,self.center.x)

let halfy = self.bounds.midY
self.center.y = max(halfy, self.center.y)
self.center.y = min(self.superview!.bounds.size.width/2.0-halfy,self.center.y)
```

Comment: How are you making your views? Interface builder? Programmatically? You could easily update the constraint instead.

Comment: its a uiimage view which can be dragged around the screen but i only want it to be dragged in the bottom half of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a container view thats on the bottom, then you can put your image in this container view. This means that your image can never get out of its container.

Comment: It takes the center of the square view and sets it to the self.view.center, which means it will move to the center of the screen. Can you provide your example code? I also made a repository where you can see how a view is animated: https://github.com/Hapeki/Example2

Comment: Mine doesnt need animation, its just a image that users are to move it around the screen when touched. So far my images is able to move around but I want to restrict how far it can be moved. The solution im looking for is a code which will enable the users to only move the image half way upto the screen starting from the bottom.

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation didnt knwo what other way to put it in, hopefully it helps thank you

Comment: You could create a container view thats on the bottom, then you can put your image in this container view. This means that your image can never get out of its container.

Comment: Thank you that worked! but what if I want the images I moved around to reset to its original location with a press of a button what code do I use for tht?

Comment: You could save the original coordinates in a variable before you move your image. Once you press the button you set the saved coordinates on your image. I'll update my answer, could you mark it so other people with the same issue can see the correct answer?